My Photo is not appearing on Canvas after filedialog.openfile
So I'm creating a Watermark App with Tkinter and PIL for my portfolio project.
I seem to have the function doing everything properly but when I try to display the image after opening it from fieldialog.openfile in does not appear on the canvas. I feel very unintelligent for not being able to do this and I feel like the fix will be simple, lol! Any help would be appreciated!
def open_directorys(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        global img_name
        canvas.destroy
        window.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file",
                                                     filetypes=(
                                                     ("jpeg files", "*.jpg *.png *.svg"), ("all files", "*.*")))
        img_name = window.filename.split("/")[-1]
        old_path = window.filename
        new_path = os.getcwd()
        print(new_path)
        shutil.copyfile(old_path,new_path+f"/{img_name}")
        print(img_name)
        func(*args, *kwargs)
    return wrapper


def add_to_canvas():
    print(window.filename)
    display = PIL.Image.open(img_name, mode='r')
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(display)
    canvas = Canvas(window, height=999, width=699)
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=img, anchor=NW)

add_to_canvas = open_directorys(add_to_canvas)

